# How to scroll view pager (accompanist library) on button click in jetpack compose Android

Tags: android-viewpager, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-accompanist

i want to scroll the view pager horizontally on button click in jetpack compose.Anyone have any idea about this ? Here i am using Accompanist library.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to use pager state like this:

```
val state = rememberPagerState()
val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
Button(onClick = {
    scope.launch {
        state.scrollToPage(state.currentPage + 1)
        // or 
        state.scrollBy(100f)
    }
}) {

}
VerticalPager(
    pagesCount,
    state = state
) { page ->

}
```